# Changing Bootstrap select's live search input type

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-select

I am using [Bootstrap Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) with the live search on.

My select however contains only a list of years. As a consequence, on a mobile device, I'd like the numeric keyboard to pop-up, not the full text. This is theoretically easy to do: change the [type of the input to `tel`](http://mobileinputtypes.com/#tel) and you're done!

However, I see no way in [Bootstrap Select's documentation](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/options/) or [issues](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=live%20search%20input%20type%20) to do this. Do you know of any way to achieve this?

---

<sub>2016-09-01: I opened a [feature request](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/1492) on Bootstrap Select's Github</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it with altering the search inputs type after the select has been loaded by listening to the bootstrap-selects events with something like this:

```
$('#mySelect').on('loaded.bs.select', function () {
    $(this).closest('.bootstrap-select').find('.bs-searchbox input').attr('type', 'tel')
});
```

Comment: Yup, I could indeed, but I'd prefer something integrated into the library. I don't like messing around, you never know what update will break it. This would be a fine workaround, though.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Hopefully your feature request will get intecrated into bootsrap select itself.

Comment: I used it as a temporary solution nonetheless. Suggested an edit if anyone wants to use it too.